# What ASCII character uses up the most memory?

Tags: memory, ascii

I've been thinking about ASCII and memory lately and couldn't find a solid answer to this question.

When a script compiled, do ASCII characters use up different amounts of memory? And if so: what ASCII character uses up the most memory?

Comment: As far as I understand all ascii characters use the exact same amount of memory, 8 bits. So I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, could you clarify your question?

Comment: @shuttle87 I wondered if ascii characters use up different amount of memory within programs on runtime, and if so which one uses up the most memory.

Comment: Are you asking if compilers encode or compress strings?

Comment: @shuttle87 Well i was wondering if for instance the character A uses up more memory upon runtime than the character Z, and if so which character would take up the most memory when a program interperts it. But since all characters appear to be 8 bits, that already answers my question, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASCII characters are a fixed width character encoding with each character represented by 7 bits. So to answer your question the different ASCII characters will all take the same amount of memory regardless of the implementation.

Because of the way in which our processor architectures are designed we typically store ASCII character in a single byte (the reason for doing so is because aligned memory access is a lot faster than having to do bitwise operations, see tripleee's comment). This means that typically any ASCII character will take up one byte of space on common computing platforms.

In contrast to this are the [variable width encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding) such as [UTF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). For future readers who come across this page it might be worth noting that the ASCII characters 0 through to 127 are represented with the same binary as they are in UTF8. This was done to help maintain backwards compatibility. Therefore *in the context of* UTF8 encoding, the ASCII characters 0 through 127 will take up less space than other UTF8 characters.

Further I haven't heard of a mainstream compiler/interpreter that compresses strings stored with ASCII characters. This would impose a runtime performance hit that many would find unacceptable. Such a space optimization would therefore be left to the user to perform.

The [ASCII wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) has a good summary of the ASCII character set.

Comment: Actually, ASCII is a 7-bit encoding, so it is theoretically possible to store it using a sequence of 7-bit slots within a sequence of bytes.  However, the processing overhead on typical processors would make this slow and complicated -- the tendency is rather to use aligned memory because aligned access is by far the fastest on modern CPUs. This means that many compilers actually space out small structures so that they are stored on, say, 32-bit boundaries if that makes sense for the CPU model.

Comment: @tripleee, that's why I made the comment about compilers not optimizing the space. Hopefully my edit makes that clearer.

Answer (score -2):

﷽ is probably the most space-consuming character. Im not sure about the coding, but it is a huge single-character. It is called "Basmala" and it means "In the name of Allah, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful."

According to a Reddit user who has now deleted their account: “It's an Arabic ligature commonly used in Urdu. It was added so someone using an Urdu keyboard can type it easier.”

I love to use this in Discord raids, because imagine 2000 Basmala characters, vs 2000 regular characters. It fills their server up a LOT. Glad I could help.

Comment: I doubt the server cares about how big (in number of pixels) are the characters ;-).

Comment: The question specifically asks about ASCII characters - The character you mention is not ASCII and therefore this does not answer the question.